# Get Posts From A Certain Post Type In An ID Array

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I have some post ids in an ID array, like:

```
$ids = array(20,34,65,126) ;
```

There is many custom post types in my project, these ids are related to different post types, but I dont know which id is related to which post type in that condition. In another word, I need to do something like this:

```
$posts = my_get_posts(
   'ids' => array(20,34,65,126),
   'post_type' => 'product',
) ;
```

That function has to be eliminate ids which is not a producy.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming this-- "That function has to be eliminate ids which is not a producy"-- means "I only want to pull the post associated with the ID if that post is a product". In that case a simple query should do it:

```
$pqry = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'fields' => 'ids', // if you only want the Post IDs
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post__in' => array(20,34,65,126)
  )
);
```

### Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: That was very short and complex usage like a tequila shot, Thank you!

Comment: Do I have to use WP_Query? "get_posts" seems not work

Comment: I prefer `WP_Query`. `get_posts` should _probably_ work but the syntax may be different. I'd have to look it up to be sure, since I virtually never use it.

Comment: It worked then, but the result is weird, it returns the array of ids which from selected post type, not posts :)

Comment: Is that not _what you asked for_?

Comment: Well, get_posts generally returns post objects, not an array as I know

Comment: `WP_Query` returns post objects as well. Maybe you want to leave out this part of the query: `'fields' => 'ids', // if you only want the Post IDs`. Did you not read note?

Comment: Ohh thats the point.. speed coding causes blinding..